# Coldfusion - How to loop through an Array of Structure and print out dynamically all KEY values?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure, coldfusion-8

Giving the Array of Structure below:

[image]

I am able to print out all values from all fields by doing:

```
    <cfset ColumnNames  = structKeyArray(ApiData[1])>                       
    <cfset ColumnLength = ArrayLen(ColumnNames)>    

    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(ApiData)#" index="i">            
       <cfdump var="#ApiData[i].Created#">              
       <cfdump var="#ApiData[i].Name#">
               ...and so on
```

Now I am trying to loop through all fields so that I dont have to actually write the
name of each field. How do I do this dynamically?
Something like:

```
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(ApiData)#" index="i">    
      <cfloop from="1" to="#ColumnLength#" index="i">
              <!---<cfdump var="#ApiData[i]." + "#ColumnNames[i]#" + "#">--->
              <!---<cfdump var="#ApiData[i].ColumnNames[i]#">--->
      </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
```

I am not a ColdFusion guy, just helping a buddy and the ColdFusion syntax is very different from .Net :-)

Thank you for your help

Comment: My vote on this question should get your reputation into 3 digits.  You owe me a beer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(ApiData)#" index="i">
  <cfset data = ApiData[i]>
  <cfloop collection="#data#" item="key">
    #key#:#data[key]#
  </cfloop> 
</cfloop>
```

Or you can use CFScript, which should be much easier to pick up.

```
for (d in ApiData)  // for-in loop for array
{
  for (key in d)  // for-in loop for struct
  {
     writeOutput(key & ":" & d[key]);
  }
}
```

use this link: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Looping/

Comment: @Max - Since you did not mention the CF version, be aware that for-in-loops with *arrays* requires CF9.0.1+.

Comment: That did not work. It seems that your solution applies to a single structure.
Remember, I have to loop through an Array of Structures.
I tried accessing the first structure of the Array by doing the following:
   <cfloop collection="#ApiData[1]#" item="key">  
   #key#:#ApiData[key]#
   </cfloop>

I am using CF 8 by the way -- thanks

Comment: I changed to: <cfdump var="#ApiData[1][key]#"> and it actually worked. Now all I need is to make it dynamic - thank you!

Comment: @Max hmm, sorry didn't know you're still in CF8.  I've updated the CFML answer and it should work for you.